# std::list deletion of elements causing trouble

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, std

I've been trying to debug this for almost half a day now and I just can't seem to find the problem. Most likely what is causing the trouble is this method:

```
//[datamember]    
std::list<Projectile*> m_Projectiles_l; 

//[predicate]    
bool removeDeads(Projectile* pProj) { 
    return !(pProj->isAlive());
}

//[the method I think might be causing the problem]
void ProjectileList::KillDeadProjectiles()
{
    std::list<Projectile*>::iterator it; 
    it = std::remove_if(m_Projectiles_l.begin(), m_Projectiles_l.end(), &removeDeads);

    if (it != m_Projectiles_l.end())
    {
        std::list<Projectile*>::iterator itDelete; 
        for (itDelete = it; itDelete != m_Projectiles_l.end(); ++itDelete) {
            delete (*itDelete);
        }
        m_Projectiles_l.erase(it, m_Projectiles_l.end());
    }
}
```

VS2010 break error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00389844 in PsychoBots.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff3a.
```

Breaking brings me to this line:

```
void ProjectileList::DoPhysicsStuff(const InputState& refInputState)
{
    KillDeadProjectiles();

    std::list<Projectile*>::iterator it;
    for (it = m_Projectiles_l.begin(); it != m_Projectiles_l.end(); ++it) {
/*[THIS line]*/(*it)->DoPhysicsStuff(refInputState);
    }
}
```

My findings:

> It gives a problem when:
>   there are more than 2 elements in the list, and a "projectile that has been added to the list earlier than a projectile that has been
>   added later on" is getting removed with this method.
>
> It gives no problems when:
>   There is only one element in the list
>   OR All the elements are getting removed at the same time.

Can anyone see any errors in this?

*If you need more code please comment, I tried to keep it small size for now.*

Comment: You're not allowed to use the iterators past the result of `remove_if`. You can erase them, but you mustn't access them, as they're not guaranteed to be in any particular state. Spare yourself all this waste of time, though, and stop using raw pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB I nearly added to the comments "please no comments about smart pointers" because I'm not allowed to use them ;) But I decided not to, since people love to make comments about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on the contents of the container beyond the iterator returned by `remove_if`. This means that you're going to have to take a different approach if you want to manage dynamic memory in the container. The easy way is to stored shared_ptr objects instead of raw pointers. Then you can just use the remove-erase idiom and everything will be cleaned up. Otherwise you'll need to carefully write the remove mechanism yourself instead of using `remove_if`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the reference of std::remove_if() carefully.
(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/)

The values in the range "it" to "m_Projectiles_l.end()" are still valid, but its values are unspecified. Most likely those values are unaltered, depending on the implementation.

This way an element may be included in the new list and still be at the the end of the old list. Deleting this element will lead to a memory exception.

You have to find another way to delete the no longer referenced elements. Consider smart pointers.